# Wicket 9 App on Widfly : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/cglib/proxy/Callback

Tags: java, wicket

I'm trying to migrate an old Wicket 1.4 App (running under JBoss) to Wicket 9 and Wildfly.

The App returns the error

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/cglib/proxy/Callback

I didn't have to deal with that lib before...
Ok, I could pick up that lib somewhere and add it to my project, but there's probably more or better to do..
Any advice?

Comment: I think there may be a version mismatch. Wicket 9 should include [CGLib 3.3.0](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/master/pom.xml#L138) as a dependency, so what I think is happening is that your project is already including an incompatible CGLib version, maybe as a transitive dependency. Could you include the relevant config of your build tool? (i.e. Maven, Gradle)

Comment: This is an "Ant" built. I downloaded Wicket 9 and overlooked the dependecies paragraph. I'll check. Thanks.